# False sharing в Java

Tags: java, многопоточность

Я объявляю два не-`volatile` поля в классе, одну изменяет одна нить, вторую - другая. Допустим, jvm их расположила рядом, так, что обе попадают в 64-байтную кэш-линию.

- Правильно ли я понимаю, что как раз этот случай и называют false
  sharingом?
- Поможет ли модификатор `volatile` (хотя бы одному полей)
  для возвращения производительности, или только установка промежутка
  между ними?

Comment: нет, `volatile` не поможет (наоборот, еще сильнее ухудшит производительность). В JMH есть [пример](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/tip/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_22_FalseSharing.java) про false sharing, в частности с аннотацией `@sun.misc.Contended`.

Comment: @zRrr пример изучу (я, собственно, и встретил эти понятия на видео-разборе jmh), но на данном этапе непонятно по теории, почему вообще возникают проблемы с производительностью? в случае, когда несколько нитей часто перезаписывают один и тот же объект (true sharing), и если он `volatile` - значит, в память всегда попадает актуальное значение (нужная кэш-строка возвращается на место), а если `не volatile` - то производительность не должна нарушаться, а должна возникать ситуация потери данных. Не могу никак связать то, что уже знаю про `volatile` и новые понятия, связанные с кэш-линиями.

Comment: Кстати, в concurrency-классах уже учитывается эффект False sharing? и об этом беспокоиться не нужно? скажем, если я буду обращаться из разных нитей к соседним элементам concurrency-коллекции, в надежде на то, что там автоматически добавлены необходимые отступы

Comment: False sharing плох тем что создает трафик на шинине данных, т.к. несколько процессоров раздлеют одну и тe же область памяти и вынуждены перезачитывать ее в кэш из-за изменений, которые им вообще-то говоря не нужны, но приводят к инвалидации линии кэша (например 8 процессоров читают первое поле, но один процессор пишет во второе и оба поля в одной лини кэша).

Эффект false sharing никчему учитывать во всех классах. Хороший пример класса, в котором он учитывается `LongAdder`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Date;

class CalcThread implements Runnable {

    private int idx;
    private long nOperations;

    public CalcThread(int idx, long nOperations) {
        this.idx = idx;
        this.nOperations = nOperations;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < nOperations; i++) {
            FalseSharing.m[idx] = (FalseSharing.m[idx] / 2) + 4;
        }
    }
}


public class FalseSharing {

    protected static volatile int[] m = new int[100];
    private final static int x = 0;
    private final static int y = 1; //99

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Long start = new Date().getTime();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new CalcThread(x, 999999999));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new CalcThread(y, 999999999));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t2.join();
        t1.join();

        Long end = new Date().getTime();
        System.out.printf("%d :: %d", m[x] + m[y], end - start); 
    }
}
```

Вот простой пример false sharing: попробуйте запускать при разных значениях поля y: 
1) при y = 0 - ситуация с true sharing 2) при y = 1 - ситуация false sharing 3) 99 - ситуация когда вообще потоки не мешают друг другу. 
Проблема  false sharing  в том, что для процессора эта ситуация с позиции производительности не сильно отличается от true sharing так как данные лежат на одном кешлайне и приходится эти данные синхронизировать между кешами - хотя вроде как используются разные участки оперативной памяти.

volatile - это указание на то что поле может измениться неожиданно для java - поэтому его нужно перечитывать каждый раз из памяти. Соответственно, ускорения от добавления данного слова ожидать не стоит.